# How to conduct IT based research in developing countries where we don't even have enough datasets for reference and analysis?

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher, research-topic, research-group

Today in developed countries technology and innovation  has reached its optimum level. But in least developed countries like Nepal, Bangladesh, etc, the scenario for research is different. Here the education syatem is also in learning phase. Few university exists and barely research oriented activities goes through academic.
We neither have any research grants to follow or enough datasets and technologies for analysis and comparision. Even the governmemt is still functioning on paper. So in such absurd situation what kinds of researches are suggested and how to do it?

Comment: What does "technology and innovation has reached its optimum level" mean? What is the optimum level of innovation? What bad things will happen if America becomes more innovative?  Why wouldn't universities be in learning phase? What other phases are there?

Comment: Apparently he means that they have reached the point of mass accessibility, not the best possible point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as equipment is concerned, in computer oriented fields I can assure you that the only thing equipment can affect is time and performance. I have done most of my personal work on an 8 year old laptop, and since half that work was on game development you can understand that lack of processing power has very visible results, but that doesn't mean you can't make anything, it will just run slow! Just mentioning it because one may argue that in developing countries equipment is scarce.

As far as datasets are concerned, I propose four options:

-You use public datasets already out there. That's not the best because you have to pick one of a few options rather than gather data fitting your needs. Also having original data is considered a pretty good thing in research, though I personally don't consider it that crucial.

-You collect your own data either within the country (it always makes an impression when you get out of the lab and get your hands dirty collecting data) or online, with the help of other institutions that may make it easier for people to complete answer forms etc.

-You collaborate with an institution in another country, or even form a network of institutions within your or similar countries, and use collective data. Forming an official research network will also have a nice ring to it and may attract some publicity.

-The final option is to contact other departments that are not working exactly on what you are working on, but may be interested in collaborating, if you can offer them some common goal. An example would be creating a database with advanced search capabilities on ancient literature, where the department of philosophy (or equivalent) would provide datasets and you would provide the framework. Note that you may have to develop software that will be easy for them to use before they can start building a dataset, but this will pay off eventually.

I personally would go for option 4, as it would also broaden the scope of interest in the project. 3 will give you some recognition outside the country, and 2 doesn't really have any specific bonuses, but it may establish the institution as self-relying and productive, especially if you do this again in the future. There are probably a couple more options I haven't thought of, but there are probably the most notable, best of luck.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to be of use.

Comment: if  you could vote up the question.

Comment: You're quite right, once I start writing I forget the world around me, done

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to get research done on publicly available data.

However, I would be silly to not mention that I left the UK for Germany to conduct my research, because the UK, as optimum as it is, wasn't the best in the world for the specific type of science I wanted to do. More importantly, it wasn't nearly as well funded for my particular area of science (its much better now though). Transferring to greener pastures is not only recommended, it's extremely normal in Science.

What did it take to get into a top German institute? Knowledge and determination. And I know for a fact that Nepal, Bangladesh, etc have plenty of knowledge and determination, because students from these countries are working side-by-side with me.

Comment: I'm from Nepal and yes South Asian do have plenty od determination. Actually I belong from Computer Science field and I wanted to some Natural Language Processing  project which could lead as a research but the absurd situation that we IT students  face is regarding the datasets. While we need huge datasets for project we don't have them available, so we should first prepare dataset which is itself a  huge project and timu consuming. Thanks for your view point

Comment: Hm. That's really interesting TechJhola. What specifically is the biggest problem? Downloading the data? Hard drives to store the data? Or getting authorization to access the data? I'm asking because i'm curious if there's any way I could help